# AWS webapp pointing to subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, hosting

I've got a AWS hosting that I need to pointing in a subdomain. For example:

The AWS IP is '123.82.52:9595/webapp' and I want to point it to 'webapp.mywebsite.com'. The domain mywebsite.com it's registered in a hosting with Wordpress.

For now I'm redirecting 'www.mywebsite.com/webapp' to '123.82.52:9595/webapp' but it's looks unsecure and ugly, and that is not what I'm looking for.

What could I do???

Comment: You need to set up a Name-based virtual hosting. I hope this link will help you http://www.tecmint.com/apache-ip-based-and-name-based-virtual-hosting/

Comment: Are you using Apache or Nginx to serve this? Also what is the OS on this instance? Amazon Linux? Ubuntu? Something else?